# Get class reference from Generic Argument in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I implement custom service provider, that receive class to get an existing instance of, so I would like to use it the following way:

```
class MyService{
   doSomething(){
      console.log("something");
   }
}

var myServiceInstance = serviceProvider.get<MyService>();
myServiceInstance.doSomething();
```

The problem that I have to write

```
serviceProvider.get<MyService>(MyService);
```

Which is ugly. Is there any way to implement service provider interface that the class reference will be retrieved internally by the generic parameter specified?

Comment: What is the type of `serviceProvider` and its implementation?  We need more info I think.

Comment: That actually is my question. What should be the implementation of ServiceProvider to make it work that way in the strongly typed mode (not any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging more I found acceptable solution, which works a bit different but removes the uglyness:

```
class ServiceProvider{
   get<TService>(serviceClass:(new(...args)=>TService)):TService{
      return this._serviceMap.get(serviceClass) as TService
   }
   private _serviceMap = new Map<any,any>
}
```

So I write class reference just one time and receive typed result:

```
let myService = serviceProvider.get(MyService);
myService.doSomething();
```

Please let me know if there is any better way.